# Can I make an array / multiple references in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project and I need to be able to set one or more task to an event, for example in garden, there is a Client and we need to cut the grass and clean the pool, instead of creating 2 events I want to create one where the 2 tasks appears and be able to select both of them in the form.

Models

```
class Client < ...
 has_many :events

class Event
 belongs_to :user
 has_and_belongs_to_many :task
 belongs_to :client

class Task
 has_many :assigned_tasks
```

I was thinking that in the controller of the events, do something like this, but it didn't work, it says it can't map

```
def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:user_id, :client_id , task_ids:[])
    end
```

in the form I tryed using collection but it didnt work, I would like to do a drop down of checkboxes or dots, but I don't know hot to do it and by doing it all with checkboxes, it gave the same error as map, it couldn map nil class nil

form

```
<%=form.collection_check_boxes :task_id,@tasks, :id,:title %>
or
<%=form.collection_check_boxes :task_ids,@tasks, :id,:title %>
```

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Unpermitted parameter: :task_ids. Context: { controller: EventsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x000002d43f70e958>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "events"=>{"task_ids"=>[""
, "1"], "client_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"2", "start_time"=>"2022-05-12", "recurring"=>"no se repite"}, "commit"=>"Crear", "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"create"} }  

IT seems it is giving atask id empty "", why?

Comment: we need to see the controller code. But to summarise, you are probably looking to https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for -- so that you can add tasks, as you are creating the event itself. Just Google "accepts nested attributes for" tutorial. --- you'll get some sample videos / code to solve your problem. This is a very common paradigm in rails.

Comment: Why? probably because you haven't initialised `@tasks` in your controller. Just copy some code based on the instructions i've given you above. that should solve all your problems

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it, In the controller I needed to change :task_id to , task_id:[]
and in the form add

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :task_id, @tasks, :id, :title, multiple: true%>
```

multiple: true
now the thing is That it can't show
I made

```
event.task.each and gave me error, it says  PG::UndefineTable there is no relation <<events_tasks>>
```

But when i do

```
 events.task_id. each
```

it allows it  but I can't show the title of the task now, please help

Comment: the only thing that I could do is to make 2 each one with the tasks that were assigned and the other with all the tasks and start compareing the ids